# How to center the elements in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using `ConstraintLayout` in my application to make applications layout. I am trying to a create a screen wheren one `EditText` and `Button` should be in center and `Button` should be below of `EditText` with a marginTop only 16dp.

Here is my layout and screenshot how it is looking right now.

activity_authenticate_content.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context="com.icici.iciciappathon.login.AuthenticationActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/client_id_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_client_id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/authenticate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_auth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/client_id_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/client_id_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/client_id_input_layout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 174, accepted):

## Update:

**Chain**

You can now use the `chain` feature in `packed` mode as describe in Eugene's answer.

---

**Guideline**

You can use a horizontal guideline at 50% position and add bottom and top (8dp) constraints to edittext and button:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/client_id_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_client_id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/authenticate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_auth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout Editor]

Comment: Thanks @Pycpik I could not understand what is the use of `<android.support.constraint.Guideline` ? Do we need to use everytime when we use `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: What is the use of `layout_constraintGuide_percent` ?

Comment: `Guideline` is just an invisible item on which you can anchor your views. `layout_constraintGuide_percent` is the percentage in the parent. Here 0.5 is 50 % height

Comment: Thanks. Gotcha. I have now two `TextInputEditText` and one `Button`. I want to place them in a center of screen. But as of now it is not https://pastebin.com/iXYtuXHg here is the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7997q2buvw76cp/q.png?dl=0

Comment: You can center the middle one and add one above and one below or put them in a `LinearLayout` and center it.

Comment: LinearLayout defeats the whole purpose of Constraints. Just make the first one top and bottom to the guide then constrain the second one to the top edit box

Answer (score 493):

There is a simpler way. If you set layout constraints as follows and your `EditText` is fixed sized, it will get centered in the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

The left/right pair centers the view horizontally and top/bottom pair centers it vertically. This is because when you set the left, right or top,bottom constraints bigger than the view it self, the view gets centered between the two constraints i.e the bias is set to 50%. You can also move view up/down or right/left by setting the bias your self. Play with it a bit and you will see how it affects the views position.

Comment: This is a much better approach than using guidelines.

Comment: This is More appropriate and also I have seen this in many talks and examples from officials.

Comment: Guidelines are better because once you have a complex layout, which will happen once marketing gets a hold of it then simplistic centering no longer works. Better to have guidelines and center to the guideline for top and bottom

Comment: this is ony useful if the textview you want to center isn't use for ajusting position of other view objects...

Comment: @Gojir4 iOS has this exact feature. Why Android doesn't is a mystery.

Comment: Nice answer! A note is that I think the latest is that you should try to use: `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` instead of Left_toLeftOf and Right_toRightOf.

Answer (score 82):

The solution with guideline works only for this particular case with single line `EditText`. To make it work for multiline `EditText` you should use `layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/client_id_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/authenticate"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_client_id"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/authenticate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_auth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/client_id_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/client_id_input_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/client_id_input_layout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: View on Nexus 5]

You can read more about using chains in following posts:

- [Building interfaces with ConstraintLayout](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7)
- [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain)

Comment: This is certainly the best answer. Other answers only work for one or two views. This one is more scalable, as it works for one, two and as many views as you want.

Comment: why with plain Button it also works for `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 33):

You can center a view as a percentage of the screen size.

This example uses 50% of width and height:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"></LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This was done using ConstraintLayout version 1.1.3. Don't forget to add it to your dependencies in the gradle, and increase the version if there is a new version out there:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

add these tag in your view

```
    app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

and you can right click in design mode and choose center.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `layout_constraintCircle` for center view inside `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@id/mparent"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

with constraintCircle to parent and zero radius you can make your view be center of parent.

Comment: best.solution.ever. Just like a "app:layout_constraintCenter_in="parent"" (which doesn't exist)

Comment: This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Answer (score 5):

Just add `android:gravity="center"` in your layout and done :)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Example

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Below would center the image on the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```