# How to place two views center horizontal in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout, centering, constraint-layout-chains

In `ConstraintLayout` I need to assume two views as a group and place this group center horizontal in the parent like the below image:

[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view_b"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_a"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've already seen [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143847/6444297) but it works when the two views have the same width. My Views have not the same width, so `Guideline` won't work!

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try chaining? Which options did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center the elements in ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143468/how-to-center-the-elements-in-constraintlayout)

Comment: @SaranSankaran: Yeas I did. I added the code to the post. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @AlirezaBideli it works when the two views have the same width. My question is not a duplicate.

Comment: you want to do both textview in center ? If you have image what type of view you want please post it

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan The question contains my goal photo

Comment: I have added my answer and let me know if it's not match to your goal image. I will edit it.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Thank you for your time. the Pawel's answer was simple and it worked.

Comment: okay NP. but if one textview size increase then it will not stay in the center. or maybe I understood your question wrong.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I'll check this out and let you know. Thanks again for your guidance

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I made the width and responded quite correctly

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your approach is good, but there's an error in how you specify the constraints. You can only set one `start` and one `end` constraint for each `View`, so you need to remove

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

from the first `TextView` and

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

from the second because they are causing the chain to be invalid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View A"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view_b"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you man, I think my brain is tired of working. I made a ridiculous mistake

Answer (score 1):

> You can achive your view using guidline and barrier.
>
> Take vertical guildline in center. After left textview start
> constraint to barrier1 and right textview end constraint to barrier2.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="View A"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="left"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:text="View B"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_a"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_a" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="right"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_b" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```